# Programmatically replace values' presentation in PHP array

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have these volume variable names. Before presenting them to the users, they need to be "retouched".

```
$unit[] = 'cm3';
$unit[] = 'barrel_petrolium';
$unit[] = 'register_tons';
$unit[] = 'ocean_tons';
$unit[] = 'gal_us';
$unit[] = 'gal_uk';
```

1. **3** needs to be converted to **³**
2. **_** needs to be converted to **one space**
3. when there is a **_xx** at the end, it needs to be converted to **(XX)**

I have no problems for the first 2 rules. How can I also apply the 3rd rule?

```
# replacements
$search  = array('3', '_');
$replace = array('³', ' ');

# units
$temp = str_replace($search, $replace, $unit); //1st and 2nd rules

$formatted[] = $temp;
print_r($formatted);
```

The result would be:

```
cm³
barrel petrolium
register tons
ocean tons
gal us
gal uk
```

It should be:

```
cm³
barrel petrolium
register tons
ocean tons
gal (US)
gal (UK)
```

Any ideas? **Thanks!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use preg_replace_callback:

```
$unit[] = 'cm3';
$unit[] = 'barrel_petrolium';
$unit[] = 'register_tons';
$unit[] = 'ocean_tons';
$unit[] = 'gal_us';
$unit[] = 'gal_uk';

$result = array_map(function ($item) {
  $item = preg_replace_callback('~_\K[a-z]{2}\z~', function ($m) {
    return '(' . strtoupper($m[0]) . ')';
  }, $item);
  return strtr($item, array('3' => '³', '_' => ' '));
}, $unit);

print_r($result);
```

pattern details:

```
~          # pattern delimiter
_          # literal _
\K         # keep out all on the left (the underscore here)
[a-z]{2}   # two lowercase letters
\z         # anchor for the end of the string
~          # delimiter
```

With the `\K` feature, only the two letters at the end will be replaced. The replacement of the underscore is the job of `strtr()` (a character translation function *and more*)

Comment: Since my setup array is a little bit more complex than the example, I had to use your solution with preg_replace instead. Thanks!

Comment: @andufo: instead of what? instead of strtr?

Comment: preg_replace instead of preg_replace_callback.

Comment: @andufo: This can not work with `preg_replace` since the second parameter can only be a string. The main interest of `preg_replace_callback` is the ability of using a function to treat the pattern matches and to return dynamically a replacement string.